# recursive backtracking only works for small inputs. Larger inputs cause stackOverFlow

Tags: java, recursion, backtracking

I am working on a problem that seems to require backtracking of some sort. I have a working recursion method but stackOverFlow happens with larger inputs. Could this be solved with an iterative implementation? I am trying to implement a method that takes in two target values a and b. starting with a = 1 and b = 1, how many "adds" would it take to reach the target a and b values? adds can either make a = a + b or b = b + a, but not both.
for example, if target a = 2 and target b = 1, it takes 1 "add". a=1 & b=1, a = a + b = 2.

```
public static String answer(String M, String F) { 
    return answerRecur(new BigInteger(M), new BigInteger(F), 0);
}   

public static String answerRecur(BigInteger M, BigInteger F, int its) {
    if(M.toString().equals("1") && F.toString().equals("1")) {
        return "" + its;
    }
    else if(M.compareTo(new BigInteger("0")) <=0 || F.compareTo(new BigInteger("0")) <=0) {
        return "impossible";
    }
    String addM = answerRecur(M.subtract(F), F, its +1);
    String addF = answerRecur(M, F.subtract(M), its +1);
    if(!addM.equals("impossible")) {
        return addM;
    }
    if(!addF.equals("impossible")) {
        return addF;
    }
    return "impossible";
}
```

Comment: Is this a yes or no question?

Comment: You have to provide more details... But it's inherent to recursion to have a stack overflow error if the method gets called a large number of times. And probably yes, if you can make the logic with iteration instead of recursion you would probably not get this error.

Comment: Please add all code necessary for your recursive method, and the call for it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. The short answer is yes. For a longer answer please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Recursive backtracking works by going through all candidate steps, do a step, recurse, undo the step.

This means that if a solution takes N items, ideally the recursion depth will not exceed N.

So: an overflow is not expected, probably too much is tried, or even infinitely recurring.

However in your case a BigInteger might be sufficient large and when using small steps (1) one would have a very recursion depth. And every call creates sufficient much. Better would be int or long instead of BigInteger.

In every call you have two candidates:

- M.subtract(F)
- F.subtract(M)

You evaluate both, one could stop when a result was found.

Also intelligence (of the math!) is missing: nice would be to prevent too many steps, finding as directed as possible a solution. In general this can be achieved by some way of sorting of the (2) candidates.

How one comes at a smart solution? First the math must be readable, what BigInteger is less. Try some sample solutions by hand, and look for a *smart* approach to order the attempts.

You can cut the recursion short, assuming keeping M and F positive:

```
if (M.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) <= 0 || F.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) <= 0) {
    return "impossible";
}
if (M.equals(BigInteger.ONE)) {
    return String.valueOf(F.intValue() - 1 + its);
}
if (F.equals(BigInteger.ONE)) {
    return String.valueOf(M.intValue() - 1 + its);
}
```

The same can be done with integer division (and modulo):

```
if (M.compareTo(F) > 0) {
    String addM = answerRecur(M.mod(F), F, its + M.divided(F).intValue());
}
```

Thinking of an iterative solution actually is possible here despite more than one recursive call, but it would not add to the quality.

Remarks:

- by java convention one should use `f` and `m` for variable names.
- is BigInteger really required? It causes a bit awkward code.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! The precondition for both M and F are M <= 10^50 and F <= 10^50. So if i'm not missing and alternative way of dealing with big integer then i think BigInteger would be required.